# A table's \cline protrudes beyond the cell's borders

Tags: tables

The following code creates two 2-by-2 tables one below the other. In the first table a horizontal line separates the two rows of the second column, whereas in the second table a horizontal line separates the two rows of the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c||c| }
\hline
A & B\\
\cline{2-2}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{tabular}{ |c||c| }
\hline
A & B\\
\cline{1-1}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `pdflatex`, the following output is produced.

[image: Different behavior of cline when used on the left vs. on the right]

Note the difference between the first and the second table. In the first table the horizontal separator is contained between the column's two vertical borders, but in the second table the horizontal separator protrudes beyond the column's right border all the way to the right column's left border.

I'd like the horizontal separator in the second table to behave in a similar way to the horizontal separator in the first table. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hhline` for that. Also, note the difference for the extremities of the upper and lower lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c||c| }
\hline
A & B\\
\cline{2-2}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{tabular}{ |c||c| }
\hhline{|--|}
A & B\\
\hhline{|~||-|}
C & D\\
\hhline{|--|}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. There are `leftpos` and `rightpos` options for hlines and clines in version `2021N` (already in CTAN, need several days to reach TeXLive or MiKTeX).

When `leftpos`/`rightpos` has value `0`, the hline/cline will touch the first vline;
when `leftpos`/`rightpos` has value `1`, the hline/cline will touch all vlines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{tblr}{ |c||c| }
\hline
A & B\\
\cline[leftpos=0]{2-2}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\vspace{.3cm}

\begin{tblr}{ |c||c| }
\hline
A & B\\
\cline[rightpos=0]{1-1}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has (at this time) no option to trim the command `\cline` (maybe in a future version).

However, that answer wants to show that `nicematrix` provides tools to programm such a command *without using the internals of `nicematrix`*.

Indeed, the environment `{NiceTabular}` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the tabular and provide access to these nodes to the user.

In the following programmation, the command `\mycline` has a starred version `\mycline*` which trims the rule on the right side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand { \mycline } { s m }
  { \__aad_mycline:nw {#1}#2 \q_stop \ignorespaces }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aad_mycline:nw #1#2-#3\q_stop
  {  
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl
      {
        \__aad_mycline:nnnn
          { \int_use:c { c@iRow } }  
          { #2 }
          { \int_eval:n { #3 + 1 } }
          { 
            \bool_if:nTF { #1 } 
              { \dim_eval:n { \arrayrulewidth + \doublerulesep } }
              { 0 pt }
          }
      }
  }

% #1 is the number of row
% #2 is the number of the first column of the \mycline
% #3 is the number of the last column of the \mycline
% #4 is the length to trim on the *right* side
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aad_mycline:nnnn 
  { \tikz \draw (#1-|#2) -- ([xshift=-#4]#1-|#3) ; }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c||c|}
\hline
A & B\\
\mycline{1-1}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c||c|}
\hline
A & B\\
\mycline*{1-1}
C & D\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).